# Multiple Threads wait for batch operation

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, batch-processing

I have a process which submits multiple tasks into an ExecutorService, say MyTask. My task requests for a value from an external service, say ExternalService. What I'm trying to do is that for the ExternalService to batch process the requests, say every 100 incoming or every 1 second and till that time to make the MyTask threads be on hold until they get an answer:

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // .... code ....


            ExternalData data = externalService.getData(id);

            // ..... code after batch ...

        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

I need service *externalService* to put on hold the *MyTask* until it does its operation in batch (by accumulating 100 requests or by waiting for 1sec) and give back the result to the task to continue.

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be accomplished by using a [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).

> CyclicBarriers are useful in programs involving a fixed sized party of threads that must occasionally wait for each other.

Create a barrier that all task can access. The arguments are the amount of tasks you want to wait for when calling `await()` and the action to perform after waiting:

```
CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(100, action);
```

Each tasks should call `await`. This will wait until a total of 100 tasks have reached this point or up to 1 second:

```
barrier.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

In case of a timeout, run `action` anyway. `action` is a runnable that calls the external service. Since `action` runs concurrently, you probably also need to make your tasks wait for it to terminate and get the results then.

---

To get the actual results of the external service I would probably use something like the following. Basically save the ID in a list and make it block until the result is ready.

```
action.addId(id);
barrier.await(...); // run batch action using all IDs
result = action.getResult(id); // blocks until result is ready
```

Comment: This a nice feature I wasn't aware of, so if my externalservice is the action I pass to the cyclicbarrier how all threads will take the result of the execution and continue? each one will have a different id, Thank you again

Comment: @tbo The action would be a wrapper around your service which also handles ids and the response. I've added an example. I think this approach should basically work but I'm sure it's still missing some things and also needs careful error handling.

Comment: At this stage I think this approach is really close to what I'm trying to do I would prefer not to execute my code on catch since if await time limit is reached a TimeoutException is thrown and the action is not executed and other threads receive a brokeBarrier exception, having said that I should catch the exceptions and act accordingly to achieve my scenario